# Trim Results After Certain Character

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table that list all of the available product ids. 
For example, 1020, 1020A, 1020B.

I am looking to group these product ids together.

Is it possible to do this via SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "group these product ids together"? The best case is if you can show us some sample data in your table and a sample of the output you wish to achieve. Feel free to edit your question to provide these details.

Answer (score 1):

to group rows with 1020, 1020A, 1020B into a group called `1020` you just need to use the substring expression in group by clause:

```
select substring(your_column from 1 for 4), ...
from ...
group by substring(your_column from 1 for 4)
```

if you have options with a different length like 102A, 102B turning into 102 you'll need a regular expression for that. The general idea is that you can use any expression, not just the column name, in group by clause

Comment: well done alexyes for seeing that question from what was posted! I think you are right.